# Netbeans java: error encountered while data entering into the database. Invalid column name 'Student Number'

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the student_details by searching from the student_No: therefore other details should appear in the other fields.

this is my search button code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (StudentID.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame (), "Enter the Student No",
                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        try {
            Connection con=DBConnection.getConnection();
            // create the statement objecty
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from  Student where [Student Number]=?");
            // fill up the parameter values from the controls
            stmt.setString(1, StudentID.getText());
            ResultSet RS = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (RS.next()) {
                jTextFieldStudentNumber.setText(RS.getString("Student_Number"));
                jTextFieldStudentName.setText(RS.getString("Student_Name"));
                jTextFieldAddress.setText(RS.getString("Address"));
                jTextFieldContactNumber.setText(RS.getString("Contact_Number")); 
                jTextFieldCourse.setText(RS.getString("Course_ID"));
                Student obj=new Student ();
                obj.setStudentNumber(jTextFieldStudentNumber.getText());
                obj.setStudentName(jTextFieldStudentName.getText());
                obj.setAddress(jTextFieldAddress.getText());
                obj.setContactNumber(Double.parseDouble(jTextFieldContactNumber.getText()));
                obj.setCourse(jTextFieldCourse.getText());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student Details Viewed Successfully", "Student Details",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Student ID", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (Exception E) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error encountered while data entering in the database" + E);
            E.printStackTrace();
        }     
    }
}
```

This is my Sql database (Student):

```
Student_Number | Student_Name | Address |Contact_Number | Course_ID
---------------------------------------------------------------------
35                 Sam            col       0754525636       5656
```

Comment: this is my Sql database (Student):

Student_Number | Student_Name | Address |Contact_Number | Course_ID
---------------------------------------------------------------------
35                 Sam            col       0754525636       5656

Comment: select * from  Student where [Student Number] should be:
select * from  Student where [Student_Number]